# FileSystemWatcher surpassing file system permissions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security, active-directory, filesystemwatcher

While experimenting with FileSystemWatcher, I've found out that it somehow surpasses my user account's permissions to files and folders, and will raise change events with information about what has changed in files and folders that you don't even have access to.

I have two questions about that:

1) Why does this happen ?
2) Is this a problem in the AD configuration ? how do I fix it ?
3) Is there any way to gather these files, or even create a FileSystemInfo of them to get more info about the files (not only the changes made on them) ?

As far as I've tried, only the FileSystemWatcher immune to the restrictions, I can't run any other thing over it, here's a list of what I've tried:

- File.Exists
- Directory.Exists
- FileInfo instance on found files
- DirectoryInfo instance on found files
- File.Copy
- File.Delete

---

**Update**: Tried helge's solution, with somethin similar to what he's sugested, not through windows' api, but through the command prompt:

robocopy /B \myserver\folder c:\somefolder

Best command name ever.

You can check through robocopy that /B stands for "backup mode", which is what helge's suggested that would be the cause to this security surpassing.

I'll try anything, I want to find out what exactly causes FileSystemWatcher to be able to watch folders I do not have permission to open. Knowing why, I want to learn both how to block FileSystemWatcher, and how to gather found files.

I'd make a survey if I was with my personal account. Please, can someone help me ? I'll write a blog post about the solution, among other things that might help anyone with the same doubt in the future.

Comment: File system permissions have nothing to do with Active Directory. They are a function of the local system only.

Comment: @Helge I disagree. If I deny permission to a folder for a group or user, I don't want them to be able to see whatever I do on this folder in any way. For me this is a hole, a bug, and should be fixed.

Comment: But permission enforcement on the local system has nothing to do with Active Directory. Whether the machine is domain-joined or not is probably irrelevent to this issue.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974004/filesystemwatcher-minimum-permissions-needed-on-target-directories/3974178#3974178) the FileSystemWatcher is based on the API function [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If that is true it explains the behavior witnessed by you - and why that is not a security hole.

As [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ReadDirectoryChangesW needs the privilege SeBackupPrivilege (which is requested by the parameter FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS to CreateFile). If a file is opened in that mode, the returned handle grants full access to the file, circumventing access checks. This feature is designed for [backup programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that need to be able to read everything on disk regardless of permissions.

This is not a security hole because the privilege [SeBackupPrivilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619%28VS.85%29.aspx) which is required for this to work is by default granted to administrators only. Administrators, and in fact anyone with physical access to a machine, are always capable of taking control of and reading every file - unless it is encrypted.

As to which functions can be used to access files in backup mode: There is at least BackupRead for reading. Enumeration is easily possible with FindFirstFile/FindNextFile. Of course this requires the real Windows API, not the crippled .NET file system functions.

Comment: Are you saying that FileSystemWatcher won't work under restricted user accounts?

Comment: I do not know. But what I am sure of is that if it gives you information about files you have no permission to view then the backup privilege is required. Maybe it uses the privilege only if available.

Comment: Got it. I'll test it more thoroughly and report whatever I find out in here!

Comment: On the Windows Command Prompt: robocopy /B \\myserver\folder <destination> does not work. even in a folder that pops up in my FileSystemWatcher, either by trying it directly, or trying to copy the parent with subfolders. Checked and /B is really backup. There's another element, it's not only the Backup mode.